# Is there any special case in c loops (while loop) where we must use increment operator before the variable instead of after?? example: ++n against n++

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

Okay, I'm learning while and for loops in C so i was trying to write a code that prints 1=0 with the initialization expression as count = 1, test expression as count < 5 and update expression as count++

I keep getting an infinite loop when i use count++ however when i use ++count, I get 1=0 in four places as i require.

Can anyone help me understand. Here's what my code looks like.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int count = 1;

 while (count < 5) {
 count = count++;
 printf("1=0\n");
 }

return 0;
}
```

In the second case,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int count = 1;

 while (count < 5) {
 count = ++count;
 printf("1=0\n");
 }

 return 0;
 }
```

I tried this and kept getting an infinite list of 1=0

```
 #include <stdio.h>

  int main() {

  int count = 1;

  while (count < 5) {
  count = count++;
   printf("1=0\n");
   }

  return 0;
  }
```

I tried this and got 1=0 in four places as i expected to get.

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main() {

 int count = 1;

 while (count < 5) {
 count = ++count;
 printf("1=0\n");
 }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, for some languages it can be more efficient to pre-increment `++x` than post-increment `x++`, because the pre-increment doesn't require returning a temporary.

Comment: Also this is well-defined code in some languages or language versions, but undefined behavior in C.

Answer (score 3):

Neither `count = count++` nor `count = ++count` are the proper way to increment a variable in C.  In fact, they cause undefined behavior.  [Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior)

Both forms of the `++` operator modify their operand in place, so you would simply write `++count;` or `count++;` by itself.  Both should behave the same in your program, and with most compilers, they will be optimized the same as well.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, your examples with two "unsequenced" side effects on `count` in the same expression invokes undefined behavior, so either version is a bug in C.

Ignoring that, this is actually a pretty good question. Because due to the above potential of bugs when mixing `++` operators with other operators in the same expression, there is a sound, general best practice rule which says that we should *never* mix `++` operators with other operators. (This rule is enforced by coding standards like MISRA or CERT among others.)

Assuming that we strive to follow that best practice rule as we ought to, then the question is how we should rewrite your loops. `for(int count=1; count<5; count++)` is the most obvious, idiomatic form. Here `count++` sits in an expression of its own where it can't cause any harm. And when we have isolated it into its own expression, we may note that it actually does not matter if we write `++count` or `count++`, they are 100% equivalent in this `for` loop.

And then we may note that prefix and postfix `++` are superfluous features in C. If we always follow the best practices, we could do without having two different operators for increment (and two different for decrement). Consequently in case you find that it matters if you use prefix or postfix increment, that alone is a certain sign that your code is fishy and should be rewritten.

There are some "old idiomatic" ways of writing C that we are *supposed* to understand though, such as implementing strcpy yourself by `while(*ptr1++ = *ptr2++);`. This is *horrible code* but it is sadly quite common, so learning prefix vs postfix is still a good idea, in case you end up reading old C code or interacting with old C programmers (whom will no doubt soon rush to the defense of this horrible code I just posted).

(Notably, other languages are very different here. Java has well-defined sequencing of your original code. Some versions of C++ do too - others have it as undefined behavior like C. And in C++ the pre/postfix does matter slightly, because of operator overloading.)